# My action is not triggering when its inside the map function React/redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am pretty new guy to react/redux.I am little bit confused why my action is not triggering when it is inside map function.It is just a simple tagging system..When user clicked on tag this function simply add to an array but it should also want to check wheather any duplicate values are added.

```
    import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as uploadActions from '../../Actions/uploadActions'

class Upload extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          suggestionLog:false,

        };
        this.handleTagSuggestion = this.handleTagSuggestion.bind(this);


    }

    handleChangeSinglePost(value, id){
       this.props.setCaptionText(id,value)
    }

    renderMaptheSingleUpload(){
        return(
            this.props.photos.photos.map((data) => {
                return(
                    <div key={data.id} className="WholeWrapperForSingleUpload">
                        <div className="imageContainerUpload">
                            <img src={data.blobData} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="ImageTitleForUpload">
                            <form >
                                <input onBlur={e=>this.handleChangeSinglePost(e.target.value, data.id)}  name="caption" type="text" placeholder="Caption This" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
    handleTagSuggestion(e){
       // console.log(e.target.value);
        if(e.target.value !== ""){
            this.props.searchTag(e.target.value);
            this.setState({
                suggestionLog:false
            })

        }else{
            this.setState({
                suggestionLog:true
            })
        }


    }
    handleTagClick(e,data){

        e.preventDefault();


        this.props.photos.postTags.map((state) => {
            if(state == data){
               console.log('Same Data')
            }else{
                 console.log("Unique")
                this.props.setPostTags(data)

            }
        })

    }
    renderSuggestion(){
         if(this.state.suggestionLog !== true){
           return this.props.loadedTags.suggestionTags.map((data) => {
                return <li onClick={(e) => this.handleTagClick(e,data.tagName)} key={data.id}>{data.tagName}</li>
            })

         }else{

         }
    }
    render(){
       //  console.log(this.props.loadedTags);
        //console.log(this.props.photos)
        //console.log(this.state)
        return(
            <div className="UploaContainer">
                <div className="UploadContainerContents">

                    {this.renderMaptheSingleUpload()}

                    <div className="tagsForupload">
                        <ul>
                            {this.props.photos.postTags.map((data,i) => {
                                return <li key={i}>{data}</li>
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="TagItForUpload">
                        <form>
                            <input onChange={this.handleTagSuggestion} type="text" placeholder="Tag it" />
                            <input type="submit" defaultValue="Post " />
                        </form>
                        <div className="suggestionSystemForTagging">
                            <ul>


                                {this.renderSuggestion()}

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        photos:state.photoUpload,
        loadedTags:state.loadedAjax
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        setCaptionText:(id,data) => dispatch(uploadActions.setCaptiontopics(id,data)),
        searchTag:data => dispatch(uploadActions.loadSuggestionTags(data)),
        setPostTags:data => dispatch(uploadActions.setTagsToPost(data))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Upload)
```

> > console.log(this.props.setPostTags),
>
> function setPostTags(data) {
>                   return dispatch(uploadActions.setTagsToPost(data));
>               }

Comment: can show more detail from setPostTags action ?

Comment: Done...........

Comment: please first test this : console.log(this.props.setPostTags), what is the output ? your action is defined ?

Comment: Yes my action is defined.Look the output i've Updated

Comment: can you try binding `this.handleTagClick` with `this` in the constructor `this.handleTagClick = this.handleTagClick.bind(this);`?

Comment: Not working!!..

Comment: Any Suggestions @phoa  Alire Valizade

Comment: Code looks fine to me actually. does `unique` show up in the log?